# Styles for Silverlight for windows Embedded Compact 7 application

Tags: xaml, silverlight-3.0, windows-embedded, windows-embedded-compact

I am working on a application development that runs on Windows Embedded Compact 7. I used silverlight 3 and made some custom buttons styles using Blend 3. It works great on blend but after in into a sub project using WEST Tools for Windows Embedded Compact 7 , the same code doesnt execute.

In the XAML , it shows **VisualStateManager** not found.

Even though I removed **VisualStateManager** & tried to have a plain style with just color definations , the application still doent work.

In the documentation it is written that ControlTemplate and Styles could be used but cannot be changed , if defined in XAML.

Please Help ! Thanks

Comment: Did you use the Expression Blend template shipped with WEST? I had no issues using the VSM (though EB marks them, you can safely ignore the warnings). Yet styling is quite difficult. For example: there is no problem styling the template of a button. But even with current updates, you cannot style check boxes or sliders without sacrificing the "proper" execution of your program. It's kind of a minefield with way to much mines to trip on. I'm currently stuck an a ridiculous trial and error procedure. Pretty pathetic for the 21. century since there is no better way of debugging either.